# Dart is there a way to measure execution time for a small code

Tags: dart

I've made some snippet involving parsing a html and wants to know if the code runs slow or not, is this doable?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can use [Stopwatch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) to measure execution time :

```dart
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
doSomething();
print('doSomething() executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
```

**Dart 2:**

- Type inference
- Optional `new`

```dart
final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
doSomething();
print('doSomething() executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
```

Comment: Can I use `stopwatch.stop()` before use stopwatch.elapsed?

Comment: Yes you can stop the stopwatch when you need.

Comment: FYI: `elapsed` returns a `Duration`, which you can invoke `inMilliseconds`, `inSeconds` etc. on to get the preferred unit.

Comment: I'm new to flutter, what two dots mean here?

Comment: @ArpitBhalla The two dots are the [cascade](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#cascades) operator in Dart. It returns the value of the expression that comes before it allowing you to chain expressions together. It's not actually needed or useful in this case. A better example would be adding to a list. "Normal": `List l = []; l.add(1); l.add(2);` The abbreviated version using cascades: `List l = []; l..add(1)..add(2);`

Answer (score 10):

If you are on the web, you can get a high resolution timer:

```
num time = window.performance.now();
```

From http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Performance.html#now

Answer (score 9):

Use devtools in profile mode for the best result

```dart
import 'dart:developer';
    
Timeline.startSync('interesting function');
// iWonderHowLongThisTakes();
Timeline.finishSync();
```

> While connected to your app, open DevTools’ Timeline events tab.

> Select the Dart recording option in the Performance settings.

https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging#trace-dart-code-performance

Comment: but how would you get the execution time with this?

Answer (score 0):

For **benchmarking** individual functions or code, I highly recommend using the official [benchmark_harness](https://pub.dev/packages/benchmark_harness) package.
Even though it uses `Stopwatch` under the hood, it for example introduces a warm-up to provide more realistic results.

```
import 'package:benchmark_harness/benchmark_harness.dart';

class TemplateBenchmark extends BenchmarkBase {
  const TemplateBenchmark(super.name);

  @override
  void run() {
     // any code to benchmark
  }
}

void main() {
  // setup benchmark
  const benchmark = TemplateBenchmark('foo');
  // run and output results
  benchmark.report();
  // or run and write duration to variable
  final time = benchmark.measure();
}
```