# How to check execution time in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I have created the basic flutter app with API integration. Now few API calls give the instant response the few are very slow. I need to find which calls are giving me a slow response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart is there a way to measure execution time for a small code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955157/dart-is-there-a-way-to-measure-execution-time-for-a-small-code)

Answer (score 2):

The new Flutter DevTools actually has a panel where you can see all your API requests similar to the browser network tab.

You need to run your app in debug mode then open DevTools and go to the [Network Panel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/network) to see them.