# How to get response time of a successful http request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, httpresponse

I'm developing an app with multiple public endpoints. I need to get data on response time of individual  http requests to optimise my app.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955157/dart-is-there-a-way-to-measure-execution-time-for-a-small-code

Answer (score 2):

Use [Network View](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/network) in DevTool. No need to change your code.